# Wordpress Custom Post Type Not Showing In Admin Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently in a wordpress customisation project.
I have a number of custom post types.One of my post types named "front_casestudy_slider" is not showing in the admin menu.I am registering the post type and the register function is called.(Tested this).But the post type is still not showing in admin menu.Why is this happening.Any fix ?.
Please find the functions.php  in
[this link](http://pastebin.com/zMrPrZBt)

The function

> register_front_casestudy_slider()

is used to register the post type

Comment: That function is not found in the pastebin posted. Please post the  relevant piece of code ( and only that! ) here, not through an external link.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped ..It is register_front_casestudy_slider() not register_front_casestudy_slide()

Comment: Anyway now I got the answer from @diggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's an error because of exceeded character length:

```
Notice: register_post_type was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>.
Post types cannot exceed 20 characters in length
```

Also, these lines are unnecessary

```
global $post_types;
array_push($post_types, 'front_casestudy_slider');
```

and also throw an error

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Tip: [Turn on WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) while developing!

Comment: Thank you for the answer..That was because of post type name length..I decreased it and solved the issue as you suggested..Thanks a lot..Actually the post_types array is used for another purpose...It is initialised first in top of the script, so no null error will be there